# Recognition of elements in a list - machine learning

Tags: python, list, machine-learning

So I have multiple lists:

```
['disney','england','france']
['disney','japan']
['england', 'london']
['disney', 'france']
```

Now I need to determine what in those lists tends to occur together.

For example if we look in this small example, we find 'disney','france' are often in the list together. As the number of documents/lists increase we may find that 'england', is always in the list with 'london'

I've looked at things such as tuples, but this occurs more in language and large text documents. The question here is how to identify these pairings/triples/n attribs that occur together.

EDIT: This is not just looking at pair. What if you had three strings come up together repetedly!

Comment: You mention (below) that your lists are in the ~100k size range.  What  is the size of your vocabulary (unique word count)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this could be a starting point:

```
import numpy as np

# I'll use numbers instead of words,
# but same exact concept
points_list = [[0,1,2],
               [0,3],
               [1,4],
               [0,2]]

scores = np.zeros((5,5))

for points in points_list:
    temp = np.array(points)[:, np.newaxis]       
    scores[temp, points] += 1
```

Result:

```
>>> scores
array([[ 3.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

The diagonal element tells you how many times a variable showed up total, and of diagonal tells you how many times, two variables showed up together. This matrix is obviously symmetrical, so it might be possible optimize on that.

Also, if your sublists are very long (you have a lot of variables), but you don't have too many of them, you might consider using a sparse matrix.

**Edit:**

Here is an idea on how to get triplets and so on.

```
import numpy as np

# I'll use numbers instead of words,
# but same exact concept
points_list = [[0,1,2],
               [0,3],
               [1,4],
               [0,2],
               [0,1,2,3],
               [0,1,2,4]]

scores = np.zeros((5,5))

for points in points_list:
    temp = np.array(points)[:, np.newaxis]       
    scores[temp, points] += 1


diag = scores.diagonal()

key_col = (scores/diag)[:, 0]
key_col[0] = 0

points_2 = np.where(key_col > 0.5)[0]      # suppose 0.5 is the threshold 
temp_2 = np.array(points_2)[:, np.newaxis] # step 1: we identified the points that are
                                           # close to 0
inner_scores = scores[temp_2, points_2]    # step 1: we are checking if those points are
                                           # are close to each other
```

Printout

```
>>> scores
array([[ 5.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  1.], # We identified that 1 and 2 are close to 0
       [ 3.,  4.,  3.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  3.,  4.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  2.]])
>>> inner_scores
array([[ 4.,  3.],                # Testing to see whether 1 and 2 are close together
       [ 3.,  4.]])               # Since they are, we can conclude that (0,1,2) occur 
                                  # together
```

As I see it now, for this idea to work properly, we need a careful recursive implementation, but  I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great answer but it does only deal with occurences of pairs of things. What if we added another list of points to the list such as [0,1,2,4] then really we can identify that (0,1),(1,2),(0,2) all come together at least twice, but we can't identify that (0,1,2) is reoccuring together.

Comment: @redrubia, I said that this was just a starting point :). I updated my answer with an idea on how to get triplets.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary where the keys are your groupings (say, as a sorted list of words), and keep a counter for each of the number of occurrences.

Comment: That would work to a certain extent, but I'd have to include every possibility derived as a key in the dictionary. So here I would have keys:['disney','england','france'], ['disney','japan'],['england', 'london'], ['disney', 'france'], ['england','france'], ['disney','england']. I think this would get large very quickly.Especially when I'm looking at around 100k lists

Answer (score 0):

when short of memory, disk can help, I usually do it this way.

```
step1. count compute the partition id of each pair and output the respecting partition-file directly ( partition_id = (md5 of pair)/partition_count, the partition process is the keypoint) 

step2. merge the count output by step1 use dict(this process is done in memory per partition,if you are short of memory, choose larger partition_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build an inverted index (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)) and then check which terms occur together more often (ie taking two terms, count how many times they occur together). That is, you record for each term the list in which it occurs. This can be pretty efficient if the size of the dictionary (the terms in the lists) isn't too big.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some kind of set logic. If things got big I'd push them to numpy.

100k lists really aren't that huge especially if they're just single words.(I just spent a week working on 6gb version of this problem with over 800 million entries). I'd be more concerned about how many **LISTS** you have.

This is obviously just a hack but it's in the direction of how I would solve this problem.

```
import itertools

a = ['disney','england','france']
b = ['disney','japan']
c = ['england', 'london']
d = ['disney', 'france']

g = [a, b, c, d]

for i in range(2, len(g)): 
    for ii in itertools.combinations(g, i):# combinations of list g in sequences from 2 to len(g)
        rr = map(set, ii)
        ixx = None
        for ix in rr:
            if ixx == None:
                ixx = ix
                continue
            ixx = ixx & ix
        if len(ixx) > 1:
            print ixx
```

result:
    set(['disney', 'france'])

Obviously this doesn't keep track of the frequencies. But that's easy after you've reduced the lists to combinational repeats.

I've assumed that you're interested in the relationship that span lists.. If you're not then I don't understand your question, nor why you have multiple lists.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution counting pairs (in pure python)

```
from string import split
from itertools import combinations, imap, chain
from collections import Counter
from functools import partial

data = iter([
    'disney england france',
    'disney japan',
    'england london',
    'disney france',
])  # NOTE could have been: data = open('file.txt')

split_data = imap(split, data)

pair = partial(combinations, r=2)
observed_pairs = chain.from_iterable(
    imap(pair, split_data)
)
sorted_observed_pairs = imap(sorted, observed_pairs)
hashable_sorted_observed_pairs = imap(tuple, sorted_observed_pairs)
pair_count = lambda: Counter(hashable_sorted_observed_pairs)  # tada!
print(pair_count())
```